# How to add VPC-CIDR authorization rule in VPN

Tags: terraform, vpn, vpc

How to add module's(vpc) output of vpc-cidr to vpn's authorization rule.

Tried the below way
cat modules/vpn/vpn.tf

```
...
resource "aws_ec2_client_vpn_authorization_rule" "vpn_vpc_cidr" {
  client_vpn_endpoint_id = aws_ec2_client_vpn_endpoint.vaya-vpn.id
  target_network_cidr    = var.cidr-vpc
  authorize_all_groups   = true
}
```

cat main.tf

```
module "vpn" {
  source         = "./modules/vpn"
  acm_vpn_server = module.acm_cert.acm_vpn_server
  vpc_id         = module.vpc.vpc_id
#  private_subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnet_ids
  subnet_ids   = module.vpc.subnet_ids
  cidr-vpc = module.vpc.cidr-vpc
  cidr-subnets = module.vpc.cidr-subnets
  env          = var.env
}
```

But getting the below error

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 79, in module "vpn":
│   79:   cidr-vpc = module.vpc.cidr-vpc
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.vpc is a object
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "cidr-vpc".
```

Comment: Does your VPC module have an output named `cidr-vpc` defined?

Comment: nope..cidr-vpc value will come from tfvars file.

Comment: Well it seems it's not. The way you are currently doing things means you are trying to reference a module output (`module.vpc.cidr-vpc`) which is not there. If it's the value is in tfvars then you need only `cidr-vpc = var.cidr-vpc`.